# Different plots when plotting subsetted vs. data by column value

Tags: r

(Edit: The issue was in how I specified my subset. subset(dat, rt>0 & rt<500) produces the correct plot but subset(dat, rt>0, rt<500) does not.)

I'm plotting the # of 'lapses' (failure to respond, or, delayed responses) by block number in a reaction time task. If it helps, true lapses are coded as -1, delayed responses are those greater than 500ms.

I'm curious as to why the following two strategies result in vastly different plots, and if there is one that should be trusted over the other. Actual plots attached at the end.

```
dat$lapsed <- 0
dat <- mutate(dat, lapsed = (rt > 0, rt < 500)

ezPlot(
data = subset(dat, lapsed==0),
dv = rt,
wid = participant,
within = block_num,
x = block_num
)

ezPlot(
data = subset(dat, rt>0, rt<500),
dv = rt,
wid = participant,
within = block_num,
x = block_num
)
```

At first I thought there might be RTs of 0 & 500 getting mixed in, but there are no instances of either in my data set.

Here's the plots:

[Plot, when subsetted by 'lapsed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1AR.png)

[Plot, when subsetted by rt>0 & <500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fayDr.png)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Maybe you are not specifying multiple criteria in your subset correctly? `ezPlot(
data = subset(dat, rt>0 & rt<500),
dv = rt,
wid = participant,
within = block_num,
x = block_num
)`

Comment: @Roasty247 Aha! That was precisely the issue, thank you.

Comment: @BrettFeltmate - you can answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in how I specified my subset. 
Subset(dat, rt>0 & rt<500) produces the correct plot, but 
subset(dat, rt>0, rt<500) does not. 
Thanks to @Roasty247 for pointing this out.